# rspec: undefined method `testimonials' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm new to `Rspec` and `Capybara`.  The error I'm getting is Navigation from homepage Visit Gallery

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path

NoMethodError:undefined method 'testimonials' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried let two different ways in order to define a variable in the spec.  I've added both of them so I can get feedback on what I'm doing wrong.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @event = Event.last
        @event.testimonials.first ? @latest_testimonial = @event.testimonials.first.id : @latest_testimonial = nil
    end
end    

feature 'Navigation from homepage' do

    before :each do
        visit root_path
        find('#nav-menu').find('h1').click #opens up navigation bar
    end

    scenario 'Visit Gallery' do
        find('#nav-gallery').find('.no_bar').click
        let(:event) {Event.last} #1st attempt at solving Rspec error.
        let(:event) {mock_model(Event, id: 3, name: "Jack & Jill", date: "2004-06-10", created_at: "2014-03-10 02:57:45", updated_at: "2014-03-10 02:57:45")} #2nd attempt at solving Rspec error.
        controller.stub(:event)

        expect(page).to have_css 'img.photos'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct - here is essentially the same content in simpler (or maybe just more drawn out by explaining things you already know) terms.

The first thing your test does is execute the `before` block, which visits `root_path`, presumably calling the `index` action on `WelcomeController`. The first thing that method does does is call `Event.last`, which returns `nil`, because your test database is empty so there is no last record to return. Then when you call `testimonials` on `@event`, you get the error you see because `@event` is `nil`.

To remedy this, you need to create an `Event` record in the database before you navigate to the `root_path` and call the `index` action. One way to do that would be to add this line before `visit root_path`:

```
Event.create(name: "Jack & Jill" [...])
```

That will create a record in the database, so `Event.last` will return something.

You would also get rid of both `let` statements and the `controller.stub` thing. Those are unnecessary now (and had other problems anyway). That should be enough to get that code to at least run.

In practice, you won't find just creating records like I've shown here to be a sustainable approach - that's where factories (with a tool like FactoryGirl) or mocks/stubs come in. Then you use `let` to define those items just once in your `before` block, and still limit the overhead consumed by creating them to those subsequent tests where they are actually used.

Regardless, the main point is that the setup of objects (and records if needed) needs to be done before you start triggering controller actions that assume those objects exist.

Comment: Is using mocks/stubs on feature tests bad practice?  I've gone ahead and implemented Factory Girl as suggested.

Comment: My own preference is to use persisted objects in integration tests but I don't put much stock in my opinion. Note that with FactoryGirl you can build stubbed versions of your objects to avoid hitting the db where you would prefer not to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`Event.last` is returning nil.

The typical (and easiest) way to do this would be to just create an event in your test, before trying to visit the site, and then your controller will use it. Feature specs should really contain the minimal amount of mocking and stubbing - they represent a real user interacting with the system.

Your stubs are not getting used (and in fact are errors in themselves). This is verified by the fact that your error is coming before they even get set.